# mockito spy does not work on a factory bean method

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test, springmockito

I have a springboot that I am writing unit test for. There is a factoryBean out of which I get service object in runtime. I want to test that a specific method on this service object is invoked. Here is the app code

```
@Component
public class AppClient {

    @Autowired
    ServiceFactory factory

    Service secretService

    @postContruct
    public void init(){
        this.secretService=factory.get("secret");
    }

    public void process(Map<String, Object> param){
        for (String key: param.keySet()){
            if (key.equals("foobar")){
                restService.handle(param.get(key));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the unit test I have

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AppTest {

  @Autowired
  AppClient appClient;

  @SpyBean
  ServiceFactory factory;

  Service secretService;

  @Before
  public void init(){
    this.secretService=Mockito.spy(factory.get("secret"));
  }

  @Test
  public void testProcess() {
    Object obj = new MyDummyObject();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("foobar", obj);
    appClient.process(params);
    Mockito.verify(secretService).handle(obj);
  }
}
```

The test fails and when I run through debugger, I see that handle is invoked. so what is wrong here?

**EDIT**

```
@MockBean
ServiceFactory factory;

@Mock
Service secretService

@Before
public void init(){
  Mockito.when(factory.get(eq("secret"))).thenReturn(secretService);
}
```

with this change, factory bean is mocked but secretService is null inside in AppClient. that is, secretService is not being stubbed in. tested through debugger.

Comment: I recommend you debug your test, and find out whether `restService.handle` really is getting called, and whether the argument really is your `MyDummyObject`.  Then you'll know whether it's your usage of Mockito that's actually wrong.

Comment: True, missed that. Sorry, I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if you see the post, I mentioned that what I observed in debugger

Comment: But is it invoked on the same MyDummyObject that you created in the test?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem invoked on same object (because  equals and hashcode is overridden)

Comment: Oh, I see your problem.  Your spy is not in the factory.

Comment: A spy is a wrapper around another object.  You've got the inner object in the factory, which means that in your class, it's the inner object being called, not the spy.  What you'll have to do is in the test, after you've made the spy, inject it back into the factory.

Comment: yes, how to inject back into the factory is the question now

Comment: You could mock the factory, and stub it to always return the right Service.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem please see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

The `PostConstruct` callback executes before the spring application entirely runs and before your test-class make some preparations on the mock of the factory. You can't be able to declare Mockito `when().then()` expectations on the code which runs in the `PostConstruct` callback.

I can suggest you make a constructor based injection in the `AppClient` bean:

```java
@Component
public class AppClient {

    private final ServiceFactory factory

    @Autowired
    public AppClient(ServiceFactory factory){
       this.factory = factory;
    }

    ...
}
```

and test this as a simple unit-test. By manually creating an instance of the AppClient, injecting a mock of the factory, execute the `init` method and verifying all that you need:

```java
@Test
void initTest(){
  when(factory.get(..)).thenReturn(..);

  AppClient client = new AppClient(factory);
  client.init();

  verify(..)
}
```